# Error in setup file while making C-Extension using SWIG in Python

Tags: python, c, swig, python-c-extension

I'm trying out C to Python Extension using SWIG 
For the toy application I've made following files

1. `hw.c`
2. `hw.h`
3. `hw.i`

Contents of `hw.h` are

```
double hw1(double r1, double r2);
```

Contents of hw.c are

```
#include<hw.h> #include <math.h>
double hw1(double r1, double r2) {
    return sin(r1 + r2);
}
```

Contents of hw.i are

```
%module mathModule
%{
 #include <hw.h>   
%}
%include<hw.h>
```

Can some one please explain me how to write this .i file? 
Contents of setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
name = 'hw'
version = '1.0'
ext_modules_list = [Extension(name = '_mathModule', sources = ["hw.i","hw.c"], include_dirs=['.'])]
setup(name=name, version=version, ext_modules = ext_modules_list)
```

When I build the module, in iPython it gives me an error when I try following code 
`from mathModule import hw1` 
But the same thing works fine when I run in python shell 
Also in the last line of setup.py, is setup a method and what is this way of passing parameters? 
Also where the name of module is decided 
 
This is the error I get in iPython

```
no module named _mathModule
```

Also can anyone say how should I specify`include_dirs` in Extension class? I tried that it should look in present directory and thus placed `.` there 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you get different behavior in iPython vs python, but I can answer some of your other questions.

> Is setup a method and what is this way of passing parameters?

setup is a function provided by distutils.core and it is here called with keyword arguments. I usually write the call like this

```
setup(
    name = "hw",
    version = "1.0",
    ext_modules = [
        Extension(name = '_mathModule', sources = ["hw.i","hw.c"],
    ]
)
```

but it is exactly equivalent to your call.

> Where the name of module is decided?

The setup file defines two modules, one called "hw" which is a python module, and one called "_mathModule" which is a compiled C extension. Both names are specified using the name keyword.

When you execute `python setup.py build`, it generates you a directory build with two subdirectories build/temp* and build/lib* where * depends on the systems you compile the code for. If you investigate these directories, you should find build/lib*/hw.py and build/lib*/_mathModule.so. After building, these directories are NOT in your python path, so you need to do an extra step before you can import them in python. This is either

- run `python setup.py install` to copy the files to a system location
  where python can find them.
- make symlinks from your main/test directory to the files in your build/lib* directory
- add build/lib* to your PYTHONPATH environment variable
- append the build/lib* folder to sys.path in the python interpreter.

The later three are only for development and testing. When distributing your code, you should always rely on the first option.

> How should I specify `include_dirs` in Extension class?

`include_dirs` are only used for compiling your extension. Once it is successfully built, the variable does not influence the search path for modules.